# Can you save money with a humidifier and air conditioner combo?

Tags: air-conditioning, humidifier

I recently discovered how powerful humidifiers can be in terms of generating cold.

What happens if you run a humidifier in a small room that has an air conditioner?

The dehumidifier can produce air up to 12 degrees cooler than the ambient temperature. The air conditioner can take away the swampy humidity.

However, taking away the swampy humidity shouldn't take away the cold the humidifier had produced. Unless the reverse happens when the humidity condenses into water?

Anyway I presented this idea to my dad and he said that removing the excess humidity with the air conditioner would make the whole thing useless as the air conditioner would expand more power to get rid of humidity. What do you guys think?

Comment: The a/c and the humidifier would work against each other, and waste power.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially, but not in the way you suggest. [Evaporative coolers (aka swamp coolers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_cooler) are an efficient way of cooling by adding moisture to the air. If the relative humidity is already high, then the additional moisture will need to be removed, with either an AC system or a dehumidifier, and any benefit will be lost and you will be worse off. If the relative humidity is low, then the additional moisture of the evaporative cooler is not an issue, and might even be desirable. In this case, there would be no need for an AC system or a dehumidifier.

If the relative humidity is moderate, you may be able to use both an evaporative cooler and an AC system. When the relative humidity is slightly low and the temperature is high, turn on the cooler. When the humidity is high and the temperature is high, turn on the AC system. Finding the perfect balance between temperature, humidity, and efficiency is going to be very hard.

Answer (score -1):

I assume, in your post, you meant to say 'humidifier'.

You have a great idea there, but not without a couple small glitches.
First, a standard HVAC system does not actually remove humidity. The perceived dehumidifying is simply the return air duct sucking the humidity from the air, but the humidity rests on the interior walls of your ducting. As you can probably imagine, that can cause issues - rust, calcium buildup, possibly mold, etc, etc
The option to have a dehumidifier installed in the ductwork is a common option in HVAC systems, but in that case, your dad would be right - you're running a humidifier up top, and a dehumidifier underneath. The costs kinda offset.

Old guys are typically always right, especially dads. ;)

Comment: Hey. I have window units and no central ac. And ac units have cold parts on them which such the humidity out of the air. Some of the acs in our house are making gallons of water a day, with no humidifiers.

Comment: correction "NPM" ---A/c units do remove humidity and the humidity does not rest on the interior walls of the ducts and I have never seen a dehumidifier installed in a residential A/C system, just  in heavy commercial systems such as schools ,  hospitals and special applications.

Comment: It's noeant to run as a dehumidifier for excessive humidity. You're going to freeze up.

Comment: NPM, please explain your last comment (there was a typo)

Comment: The evaporator coils are not meant to be run as a dehumidifier for excessive moisture. You're going to freeze up the coils.

Comment: Dehumidifiers are more common here in the south.

Comment: NPM--The coils of an air-conditioning unit will only freeze when the air flow over the coil is too low, when there is a problem with the refrigerant charge or other A/C problem, or when operating the A/C unit when the  outdoor temperature  is lower than it was designed for  unless the unit has devices installed to allow for low ambient operation.

Comment: Well d.george, you should call the patent office, then Lennox & Trane, and tell them you have a fool-proof plan to cool houses now - pump humidity into the house. After all, the HVAC system will be unaffected. ....Dude, I'm not discussing this. You're overlooking so much, there's nowhere to start.

Comment: why are you guys always talking about a hvac system. I have a 6000 btu window ac unit lol.

Comment: That is it, I am done trying to inform those of you that speak on subjects you have no training in! Jeeezzz.

Comment: I agree with @d.George both window and central AC systems remove some humidity. When warm humid air flows across the evaporator coil moisture condenses just like on a glass of ice water. Centeral AC systems have a condensate drain that gets rid of the moisture where the window units allow it to dribble out the back. A dehumidifier is a AC unit the difference is the heat exchanger or condensing coil is in the same air space so there is no real cooling the air being passed over the evaporator is cooler but the air over the condenser is warmer so there is no net cooling.+